# Dropdown select on multiple Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-select

I am looking for a way to change my selected value on a select box, but based on 2 attributes for example:

```
<select id="user_select">
  <option value="1" value2="1">John</option>
  <option value="2" value2="1">Jonas</option>
  <option value="1" value2="2">George</option>
  <option value="3" value2="1">Carl</option>
</select>
```

For example i want to set George as the selected value, normal $('#user_select').val(1) won't work as it it will cause confusion between John and George.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you using duplicates values?

Comment: You should opt for single unique value. It's more convenient to maintain.

Comment: i have different type of users, which might have the same ID, but will have different types, so i am listing their ID and Type, unless there is a better way of doing it?

Comment: @JPVeldtman Not certain what application , expected result is ?

Comment: Users with the same IDs? That's the real problem.

Comment: I join a User Table and a TempUser Table, but showing both their data in the select list by joining the 2 tables, then i would like to set the logged in user as the selected value

Comment: probably you can concat both the values and map that with the select item value field which should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks, I will generate the values as T1 and U1, this should sort out the issue as i will know if the user that is logged on a TempUser or a normal User. and easy backwards usage.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to select by value and value2

```js
$('[value="1"][value2="2"]').attr('selected',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="user_select">
  <option value="1" value2="1">John</option>
  <option value="2" value2="1">Jonas</option>
  <option value="1" value2="2">George</option>
  <option value="3" value2="1">Carl</option>
</select>
```